# Request Interceptor to enforce Catch block in response

Tags: angularjs

Here is my service's response:

```
response = response.then(function (data) {
        return data.data;
    });
    response.catch(function (data) {
        $q.reject(data);
    });
    // Return the promise to the controller
    return response;
```

In Interceptor I am returning:

```
return $q.reject();
```

But, still I am getting back into:

```
response.then
```

Is possible to get back into the catch block?

Thanks

Adding more code:

```
.service('APIInterceptor', function ($q, $rootScope, UserService) {
var service = this;

service.request = function(config) { 
    return $q.reject();
    //return config;
};
service.responseError = function (response) {        
    return response;
};
})
```

Comment: Can you post more code?

Comment: Added more code. Seems like if I remove service.responseError from the Interceptor it does go into the catch block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that your `.request` creates an error (by doing `return $q.reject()`), but your `.responseError` "handles" that error (by virtue of being there), thus resulting in the overall successful resolution.

Indeed, removing `.responseError` handler makes the error bubble up to `.catch`. Alternatively, you can also `return $q.reject()` in `.responseError`.